# Change Font of ggplot graphic in shiny web app into a font from google

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, fonts

I was able to import the font Lato in my shiny web app from google and to using it,
but I want to change the font in my ggplot2 graphics into Lato too,
but with the family argument it doesnt work, because ggplot want to access only windows fonts.

[Lato header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B7OJ.png)

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


#library(showtext)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('

         @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap");
         
         #sidebar {
         background-color: white;
         }
         
         * { 
         font-family: "Lato";
         }')
  )),
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(id="sidebar",
                 sliderInput("bins",
                             "Number of bins:",
                             min = 1,
                             max = 50,
                             value = 30)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
    ))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
   
    
    ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x = x)) +
      geom_histogram( bins = 30) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, 
         title = "Title should be in Font Lato") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10, family = 'Lato'))
    
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
Zeichensatzfamilie in der Windows Zeichensatzdatenbank nicht gefunden

Any ideas why ggplot cannot find Lato?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `showtext` this could be achieved by adding

```
font_add_google("Lato", "lato")
showtext_auto()
```

to your code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)
#> Loading required package: sysfonts
#> Loading required package: showtextdb

font_add_google("Lato", "lato")
showtext_auto()

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('

         @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap");

         #sidebar {
         background-color: white;
         }

         * {
         font-family: "Lato";
         }')
  )),
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      id = "sidebar",
      sliderInput("bins",
        "Number of bins:",
        min = 1,
        max = 50,
        value = 30
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2] # Old Faithful Geyser data
    ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x = x)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
      labs(
        x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL,
        title = "Title should be in Font Lato"
      ) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, family = "lato"))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8198
```

[image]

**EDIT** Test with a different font.

```r
font_add_google("Gochi Hand", "gochi")
showtext_auto()
```

[image]

Comment: The error msg. is gone, but the title isnt unfortunatly in lato

Comment: Hm. Weird. In the reprex and when I run the app on my machine it's "Lato". I just added another image with a font where it's visible on first glance.